# Will this mulberry trunk injury heal completely?

Tags: trees, plant-health, mulberry

Tree age: 2 year

Injury age: about 8 months

Type: mulberry

Trunk diameter at injury: about 2 inch

Max trunk diameter: about 2.8 inch

[image]

[image]

**Update after about 5 months. September 28, 2023**
Very close to complete healing. Sorry for night photos.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the tree should heal completely, and probably by the end of next summer.

A general rule of thumb when it comes to this type of bark damage is if the amount of bark removed is 75% or less, the tree will heal itself over time. This is somewhat dependent on the tree's species, of course. I had a chokecherry with bark that was nearly completely rubbed off by a deer that recovered just fine, and I personally know of a ginkgo that was rubbed over 80% that also recovered. Mulberries are very fast growers and yours is well on its way to recovery.

Comment: You were so right @jurp we are almost there. I have added updated photos above.

Comment: @EresDev Very glad to see that the tree has recovered so well!

Comment: Oops, now we have worms in the injury https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/65396/worms-are-eating-my-mulberry-tree-injury