# Worms are eating my mulberry tree injury

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, worms, mulberry

My mulberry tree had a two big injuries last year. One due to heavy scratch, and second I cut wrong branch at wrong place. It has been healing it very nicely so far, almost 90% done. But yesterday I saw worms in it. The sap has started to leak a few weeks ago and it also used to leak last year when tree got this injury. What should I do now about the worms?
Worms look like maggots but their size is very small, like 2mm to 3mm long.

Yesterday, I cleaned the worm using pressure water and applied soap water mixed with neem oil, but it didn't work. Worms are again here today.

Here you can see injury & worms in it: https://youtube.com/watch/z1-_iUK_Jzc

Here I caught single worm to examine: https://youtube.com/watch/2JziDJMTF3E

[image]